# ASP.NET Repeater Control - Getting Hiddenfield value inside the repeater control

Tags: c#, asp.net, accordion, repeater, hidden-field

I have a hiddenfield inside a repeater control and a button outside the repeater control. below is the asp.code that i have.

```html
<asp:Repeater ID="rptAccordian" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptAccordian_ItemDataBound">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <div class="s_panel">
      <h1>
          <a href="#" data-content="Tool tip"><%# Eval("Name") %></a>
      </h1>
      <div>
        <p>
          <small><span style="font-family: 'Segoe UI'; font-weight: bold;">Category Objective: </span><span style="font-family: 'Segoe UI'"><%# Eval("Objective") %></span></small>
        </p>
        <p>
          <small><span style="font-family: 'Segoe UI'; font-weight: bold;">Category Riskscore: </span>
              <code><%# Eval("Score") %><span>%</span></code></small>
        </p>
        <p>
          <code>
               <img src="Content/img/add.png" /><asp:LinkButton ID="Add" runat="server">Add Question</asp:LinkButton>
          </code>
        </p>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnCategoryID" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("CategoryID") %>' />
      </div>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
<div id="modalpopup">
  <asp:Button ID="btnInsertQuestion" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btnInsertQuestion_Click" />
</div>
```

My Backend code is as follows.

```
protected void btnInsertQuestion_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HiddenField hf = (HiddenField)rptAccordian.FindControl("hdnCategoryID");
    catID = Convert.ToInt16(hf.Value);
    Response.Write("ID is") + catID;
}
```

There are 13 repeaters and each repeater will have different CategoryID for it. I have a Link Button called Add inside each repeater and when I press that button I will have a modal popup open and it will have a button. On clicking that button I need to display the appropriate CategoryID which belongs to that repeater control in which I clicked the ADD link button.

However, the hiddenfield hf is showing as null and I'm not able to get the value of the hiddenfield of that accordion.

Comment: Use this link it will be useful.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29862571/dropdownlist-is-not-showing-the-selected-value

Comment: You are looking for an `HiddenField` with "hiddenid" id, but the actual id inside you aspx is "hdnCategoryID".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have acheived my answer using jQuery. I found the control hdnCategoryID and its value using jQuery and i assigned that value to a new hidden field and retrieved that value to my click event.

Answer (score 2):

You have to get the repeater item to access the hiddenfield:

```
protected void btnInsertQuestion_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {  
            for (int i = 0; i < rptAccordian.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                var item = rptAccordian.Items[i];

                var hf = item.FindControl("hdnCategoryID") as HiddenField;
                var val = hf.Value;
            }
        }
```

**UPDATED**

```
protected void Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var lb = sender as LinkButton;
            var par = lb.Parent.FindControl("hdnCategoryID");

        }
```

Comment: Hi, Tried with your code. However i'm getting error at i < r.Items.Count in the for (int i = 0; i < r.Items.Count; i++) statement as An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in App_Web_sc5r5wz1.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: it looks like the items collection is null. Do you databind the repeater again on postback?

Comment: yes. I am binding the repeater in the page load (!this.IsPostBack)

Comment: Hi Legends. The code is working but its picking up incorrect categoryid value. The category id values are pulled from database and are binded to the repeater. So one repeater will have a static categoryid value and will not change. However since your code has a for loop, it loops through every accordion and get the categoryid value of each accordion and the category id value gets overwritten each time when loop is executed. This is not correct for my scenario. I want the categoryid value from the hiddenfield in which I clicked the ADD button.

Answer (score 1):

You can get that without using hiddenfield. You need to declare `Add` LinkButton in repeater like this.

`<asp:LinkButton ID="Add" runat="server" CommandArgument = '<%# Bind("CategoryID")'%>  OnClick = "Add_Click">Add Question</asp:LinkButton>`

You have written code for `btnInsertQuestion` button click, where as you requested to get `CategoryID` in Add button click, so I am assuming your requirement is correct, but you have typed something else.

To get CategoryId in Add button click , you need to write like this.

```
protected void Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Get the reference of the clicked button.
    LinkButton button = (sender as LinkButton );

    //Get the command argument
    string cat_id = button.CommandArgument;
    // Type cast to int if application and use it.
}
```